# Strange behavior on .all? { block }

Tags: ruby

I was debugging some code today when I realized that [Enumerable#all?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) was not behaving like I thought it would.

I use this method to determine when to return a value right away.  It looks something like this:

```
def some_method(hash)
  unless hash.all? { |k, v| v.is_a? Float }
    return hash
  end

  # some other business logic
end
```

Sometimes however this method gets sent an empty hash and the results of `all?` are not what I expect.

Here are a few normal scenarios:

```
[7] pry(main)> {'count' => 1}.all? { |k, v| v.is_a? Float }
=> false
[8] pry(main)> {'count' => 2.5 }.all? { |k, v| v.is_a? Float }
=> true
```

Here's where it gets odd:

```
[6] pry(main)> {}.all? { |k, v| v.is_a? Float }
=> true
```

I wouldn't expect this to return true, in fact I would expect to get back a `"No method .is_a? for NilClass"` but instead I get back true.  Does anyone know why this is?

Ruby 2.2.0

Comment: FYI You couldn't get a no method exception since `.is_a?` is a method on NilClass. `nil.is_a? Float => false`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for `No method .is_a? for NilClass` error to be thrown since the block never gets executed (besides that `.is_a?` is implemented on [`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) and `NilClass` is apparently derived from `Object`.)

One might expect `all?` to return `false` on empty enumerator, but it’s like a matter of design.

You might click on `show code` within the documentation and make sure that the approach “assume the result is true and turn it to false on the very first block returning false” is taken for this method implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The key part of the documentation is "The method returns true if the block never returns false or nil."

With `{}.all? { |k, v| v.is_a? Float }` the block is never executed (since the map is empty). As a result, the block never returns false or nil and thus the method returns true.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning behind this is quite simple when you look at the [documentation for the `all?` method, as defined in the Enumeration Module in Ruby 2.2](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

> The method returns true if the block never returns false or nil

The `all?` method executes the block for every element of an enumerable. Because an empty hash contains nothing to iterate over, the block never gets executed. Hence the method returns `true`